# extjs4 selectors itemid column editor

Tags: javascript, extjs4

I'm trying to select the itemid editor of my column, but I can not intercept the event from my controller.

view:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.fatturaVendita.FatturaVendita', {
    extend: 'Ext.window.Window',

    height: 700,
    id: 'fatturaVendita',
    width: 1000,
    collapsible: true,
    title: 'Fattura Vendita',
    maximizable: true,

    initComponent: function() {
        var me = this;

        Ext.applyIf(me, {
            items: [
                {

                                   .....
                                      xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                                    itemId: 'clnCodiceArticolo',
                                    width: 45,
                                    sortable: false,
                                    dataIndex: 'CodiceArticolo',
                                    text: 'Art.:',
                                    editor: {
                                        xtype: 'textfield',
                                        itemId: 'txtCodiceArticolo',
                                        msgTarget: 'side'
                                    }
                                },
                                 ......
```

controller:

```
......
        this.control(
               '#fatturaVendita  #txtCodiceArticolo':
                 {
                     afterrender: function (f, e) {
                         alert("change");
                     },

                     specialkey: function (f, e) {
                         alert(specialkey);
                         var me = this;
                         if (e.getKey() == e.ENTER) {
                             if (getWin(me.getIdWin(), '#txtCodiceArticolo').getValue() == "") {
                                 Ext.create('MyApp.view.fatturaVendita.Ricerca', { grd: "grdCorpoFatturaVendita", store: "ArticoloStore", dataDescrizione: "Descrizione", testoDescrizione: "Descrizione", idCampo: f.id, codice: f.name, descrizione: "DescrizioneArticolo" }).show();
                             }
                         }
                     },
                 },
   ......
```

all field my grid column and editor use itemid , i use id only for my windows "fatturaVendita".
But this code not work.how can I do? =(

similar to this example but I can not make it work. I can not seem to intercept the event SpecialKey of textfield of the grid:
http://jsfiddle.net/brux88/S2rdL/20/

**

> UPDATE:

**
thank you for help, now work but i don't understand. I have a multi-window application. I'm using itemid for the controls while only the id for each window. If I have two windows and I have the same itemid (txtCodiceArticolo) how does extjs figure out which event I want to unleash? In fact, in my controller if I use

```
          this.control({  
  '#idWindows #itemId': {
                specialkey: function (f, e) {
                     if (e.getKey() == e.ENTER) {
                             alert("2");

                     }
                 }
        }
```

. I do not only work for the column editor.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle to demonstrate your problem?

Comment: hi because i use sencha architecth for my view, i try a make un jfiddle. I would like to intercept the controller, the special key event of textfield of my column, having assigned an item id

Answer (score 1):

I spotted one critical error in your fiddle that your controller's `init()` function isn't called, so your event handler will never run.

The `init()` function is called automatically by the framework if you include controller in your `Ext.application` function like this:

```
Ext.application({
    controllers: [
        'YourApp.Controller'
    ],
});
```

However, if you're trying to instantiate a controller manually, you will need to call `init()` manually:

```
Ext.define('YourApp.Controller', {...});
var ctrl = Ext.create('YourApp.Controller');
ctrl.init();
```

Here is the [official doc](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/guide/mvc_pt2) for this point.

I made your fiddle work, but it seems only the ENTER key triggers `specialkey` event. Check it out http://jsfiddle.net/jaux/Yqtv3/

*Update:*

You have multi-window and each window has different id, say their ids are 'window1', 'window2', etc.. In the controller, you will have something like:

```
this.control({
    '#window1 #txtCodiceArticolo': {
        specialkey: {...}
    },
    '#window2 #txtCodiceArticolo': {
        specialkey: {...}
    }
})
```

This is saying that the first 'specialkey' belongs to window1's txtCodiceArticolo and the second 'specialkey' belongs to window2's txtCodiceArticolo.

Comment: I'd already done this way. but failed to intercept any event. =( why?